# Generate random LTL Formulae

Tags: code-golf, random, generation, logic

An [LTL Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) l is defined by the following grammar (where <x> describes the non-terminal symbol x):

```
<l> ::= <b> | F <l> | G <l> | X <l> | (<l> U <l>) | (<l> W <l>) | (<l> R <l>) 
            | (<l> & <l>) | (<l> \| <l>) | !<l>
<b> ::= BVar | True | False | (<i> < <i>) | (<i> <= <i>) | (<i> > <i>) | (<i> >= <i>) 
             | (<i> = <i>) | (<i> != <i>)
<i> ::= IVar | -128 | -127 | ... | 127 | (<i> + <i>) | (<i> - <i>) 
             | (<i> * <i>) | (<i> / <i>)
```

(I escaped a pipe to denote boolean or. You should not print that backslash in your output)

BVar and IVar represent variables of boolean and integral types respectively. Each must be one of four possible single character variable names, and there may by no overlap between BVar and IVar. For instance, you may choose a,b,c,d for BVar and w,x,y,z for IVar

Note that all binary operators must have parentheses around them and that no other parentheses are allowed.

Your task is to write a function that takes one input encoding the maximal nesting depth of an LTL formula and prints a random formula limited by that depth (but not necessarily exactly that depth). The distribution does not have to be uniformly random, but each possible formula has to have a non-zero chance of being generated.

You may use ≤, ≥, and ≠ instead of <=, >=, and !=.

You may add or remove whitespace as you see fit. Even no whitespace at all is allowed.

Examples:

```
f(0) -> True
f(0) -> d
f(1) -> (a&b)
f(1) -> Fd
f(1) -> (x<y)
f(3) -> (G(x!=y)|Fb)
f(3) -> (x<(w+(y+z)))
```

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: May we use `≤`, `≥`, and `≠` instead of `<=`, `>=`, and `!=`?

Comment: That is allowed. I will update the challenge accordingly.

Comment: What is the "*nesting depth*"?

Comment: Is everything in `<i>` evenly divided in terms of randomness? So these four `(<i> + <i>) | (<i> - <i>) | (<i> * <i>) | (<i> / <i>)` each have a chance of 1/260 to occur (and -128 through 127 also each has a 1/260 chance to occur)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think (not sure) this refers to the maximum depth of `<i>`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess this also means that if the input is 0, the integer -128 through 127 have a 1/256 change of occurring for `<i>`; if the input is 1 it at first has first a 1/260 chance of occurring, and if it happens to be `+-*/` (4/260 chance), the next time it randomly selects `<i>` it has a 1/256 chance again because we have reached our maximum nested depth. Am I understanding what you've meant with _maximal nested depth_ correctly, @Sacchan?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The probabilities do not have to be equal. As I stated, every part just has to have a non-zero probability of occurring.

Nesting depth refers to the longest path in the syntax tree of the formula. If you have a depth of zero, you can only have a node without children (such as a constant or a variable). A nesting depth of 1 gives a unary or binary operator with the children having a nesting depth of at most 0. And so forth.

Comment: `<l>` cannot derive `55`, as far as I can see. And the path in the syntax tree for `True` has length 2: `<l> -> <b> -> True`

Comment: It seems (from the examples) that we should read "maximal nesting depth of an LTL formula" liteally (i.e. it is the nesting depth of the resulting *formula* rather than that of the syntax tree path taken, as assumed by @rici above). Could you clarify this?

Comment: Also, if I am correct, could you clarify whether the nesting depth of `Fd` would be zero or one?

Comment: @rici: You are correct, 55 was an erroneous example. I have removed it.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan: You are correct. Fd would be a nesting depth of one (since the Tree would have F as root node and d as its child)

Answer (score 4):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 251 bytes

**249 bytes code + 2 for `-pa`.**

```perl
$d=I;sub a{map"($d$_$d)",@_}@I=(w..z,-128..127,a qw{+ - * /});@L=(@B=(a..d,True,False,a qw{< <= > >= = !=}),B,FL,GL,XL,"!".($d=L),a qw{U W R & |});$_=$L[rand@L];0while s/L|B|I/@{$&}[rand@{$&}]/e;$;=$_;s/[^()]//g;0while s/\)\(//g;$_=y/(//>"@F"?redo:$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU1PS8MwHL37KX4rYSSaJm4gillq6KFSyEkUha2WSKIWaltbR9G2X321owfvHh483t/K1fnFOCIrY9HsX8B0H6byMLIoRZZ4VKWDiiVuGfuh/mp9xdhqfUkNfLbdGfhwCnwgQmmJVSixYczS@3rvaGTyxs2xDWwkBBBIkLCQA6EhjTS91fRJU2/hselLajJnH@AR7mAJ/TSKUon0tjaFVToR5@17ljtouO7DPuaqQ8thNo8s4U4gIVEqGr59xiTh/O2vsiM7fBSmxW8@scBTkXdTO1teo3HMiteTf@JQVl9ZWTSjX5n8Fw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>298</s> <s>293</s> <s>283</s> 279 bytes

```python
def f(n,t=1):s,*X=c([[(c(V[t>1]),)],[('%s',0),(c('FGX!')+'%s',1)]][t&1]+[(f"(%s{c('<U+≤W->R*≥&/=|+≠'[t::3])}%s)",*[2-(t&1)]*2)]);return n and s%tuple(f(n-1,x)for x in X)or c(V[t>1])
from random import*
c=choice
V=['True','False',*'abcd'],[*map(str,range(-128,128)),*'wxyz']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9NTsMwEIX3OYWplNrjOKJOF6BCuix7BCWS5UVwExqpdSLbES0/B@gtWMDFepEwYoHYIHUxevON5o3edPuwbu10GFZVTWpmRcglzLzgRW6YUsywpQpzqUGAForR2FMxAYFzurgpzigkPyMJWqswljpRrB6x2L/iwvV9cjx8PqTzW348fI3P8zfkD6rCbDbV8B57GAmuspShETTPQMOVq0LvLLGktCvi49B3m4phrlSKHdStIzvSWFIAdr/Rotq1W@LQgdJsu9YFHpncrNvGVNEyV/TO9RUVdFFuPCqn5aNZUfyHb8uO@eAEmp8qlsrsUmAB4M7zbv9C9dC5xgaCESYA0QkgT4Ppv3DxFzK8PXwD)

Comment: Generated "(XF((dW-91)U(46|21))&c)" for me, and (46|21) is not a valid subformula, same for (dW-91). You use integers where you have to have bools

Comment: @Sacchan Ah, I returned either a bool or int when the level was 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>456</s> <s>423</s> <s>419</s> <s>407</s> 403 bytes

```java
n->{int r=R(9);return r>4?(r<8?"FGX!".charAt(r-5):"")+b(n):"("+b(n)+"UWR&|".charAt(r)+b(n)+")";};int R(int i){return i*=Math.random();}String b(int n){int r=R(9);return r>7?"abcd".charAt(r%4)+"":r>6?"True":r>5?"False":n>0?"("+i(n)+"<≤>≥=≠".charAt(r)+i(n)+")":b(n);}String i(int n){int r=R(n>0?256:261);return(r-=128)>131?"wxyz".charAt(r+2&3)+"":r>127?"("+i(--n)+"+-*/".charAt(r-128)+i(n)+")":r+"";}
```

-8 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bZJLTsMwEIb3nGKwRGU3SmjSB9A0idjAii4KCCTEwk0CuDRO5bgUKDlAb8ECLtaLFDs1BCEkWx6//vk0/0zoE7XzWconyeMmntKigDPK@HIHgHGZijsapzDUW4BzKRi/hxirG@DEV4elmmoMgUMAG26HS30nghE@Ir5I5VxwEGEnwmJwGKGT0@td5MQPVBxLLOwu6SNErDHmKsCoCix0eTVqvNWviDkmyC99LT6q0jOyNPKsGZxR@eAIypM8w8QvDefYcP6LdBAhOo6TOs9eRyVBfRH2InQh5qkOuwqZTgsV87AVaURWsQzWq49wvfoM1qv336TMkPY18g8H@8uhxbxur@/13G8iVY3A9Q5J6LbdCC2eX15rXctrtA2b6x0YDNvWqSy7uf@roFqhhhDqj19uAGbz8ZTFUEgq1fKUswQy5THe8t3cAiVbg7XzkCknebqoNrgyGeAuF9uqBy0f2CBwW3q1LPNPtcZLIdPMyefSmSlROeU4c7ijWoUYibLqlnLzBQ)

NOTE: Due to the rule "*The distribution does not have to be uniformly random*", I've been able to golf some parts by using modulo-4 on the input or random integer for the characters `"abcd"` or `"wxyz"`, and change `Math.random()*10` to `Math.random()*9` and change the ternary a bit. Personally I prefer to have the randomness equally divided for each method, which is **<s>456</s> <s>441</s> 404 bytes** instead (and is explained below):

```java
n->{int r=R(10);return r>4?(r<9?"FGX!".charAt(r-5):"")+b(n):"("+b(n)+"UWR&|".charAt(r)+b(n)+")";}int R(int i){return i*=Math.random();}String b(int n){int r=R(9);return r>7?"abcd".charAt(R(4))+"":r>6?"True":r>5?"False":n>0?"("+i(n)+"<≤>≥=≠".charAt(r)+i(n)+")":b(n);}String i(int n){int r=R(n>0?256:261);return(r-=128)>131?"wxyz".charAt(R(4))+"":r>127?"("+i(--n)+"+-*/".charAt(r-128)+i(n)+")":r+"";}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bZLdTsIwFMfvfYpjL0zLssmQD2Fsizd6BReo0cR40X0gRdaRroCIewDewgt9MV4E2zGBGJM2Pf36n1/O/4zpnJrpNObj6HUbTmiWQY8yvjoBYFzGYkjDGPp6C3ArBeMvEGJ1A5w46jBXU40@cHBhy01vpe@EO8B2lTgiljPBQXh1H4tu20fXN4@nyApHVFxJLMwG6SBEjABzFWBUBAa6fxicfRxekfKYICd3tPqgyM/IqpRnFbdH5cgSlEdpgomTl6BBCbpnah8htXxEgzDa5xngOlFZUEd4TR/diVmsw4ZippNMxdyr@pqRFTDdzfrL26y/3c368xiVlagdzbwHYX9BtFit0ezUmvYvkiqHa9cuiWdf2D5avC3f/0Oza62SwjR1JsOsnB8VVAscGIT64@RbgOksmLAQMkmlWuYpiyBRJuMd3tMzULJzWFsPibKSx4tigwuXAYap2FXdrTrAuq5d1athlP9UbywzGSdWOpPWVInKCceJxS3VK6SUyIt2ybc/)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                     // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  int r=R(10);           //  Random integer [0,9]
  return r>4?            //  Is it [5,9]:
    (r<9?                //   Is it [5,8]:
      "FGX!".charAt(r-5) //    Return a leading character
     :                   //   Else (it's 9):
      "")                //    Return nothing
    +b(n)                //   + call to method `b(n)`
   :                     //  Else (it's [0-4]):
    "("                  //   Return opening parenthesis
    +b(n)                //   + call to method `b(n)`
    +"UWR&|".charAt(r)   //   + middle character
    +b(n)                //   + another call to method `b(n)`
    +")";                //   + closing parenthesis
}                        // End of method

int R(int i){            // Method `R(i)` with integer as both parameter and return-type
  return i*=Math.random();
                         //  Return a random integer in the range [0,i)
}                        // Else of method `R(i)`

String b(int n){         // Method `b(n)` with integer parameter and String return-type
  int r=R(9);            //  Random integer [0,8]
  return r>7?            //  Is it 8:
     "abcd".charAt(R(4))+""
                         //   Return random from "abcd"
   :r>6?                 //  Else-if it's 7:
    "True"               //   Return literal "True"
   :r>5?                 //  Else-if it's 6:
    "False"              //   Return literal "False"
   :n>0?                 //  Else-if it's [0-5] AND the input is larger than 0:
    "("                  //   Return opening parenthesis
    +i(n)                //   + call to method `i(n)`
    +"<≤>≥=≠".charAt(r)  //   + middle character
    +i(n)                //   + another call to method `i(n)`
    +")"                 //   + closing parenthesis
   :                     //  Else (it's [0-5] and the input is 0):
    b(n);                //   Call itself again, hoping for random [6-8]
}                        // End of method `b(n)`

String i(int n){         // Method `i(n)` with integer parameter and String return-type
  int r=R(n>0?256:261);return(r-=128)
                         //  Random integer in range [-128,128]
                         //  OR [-128,132] if the input is larger than 0
  >131?                  //  If it is 132:
     "wxyz".charAt(R(4))+""
                         //   Return random from "wxyz"
   :r>127?               //  Else-if it's [128,131]:
    "("                  //   Return opening parenthesis
    +i(--n)              //   + call to `i(n-1)`
    +"+-*/".charAt(r-128)//   + middle character
    +i(n)                //   + another call to `i(n-1)`
    +")"                 //   + closing parenthesis
   :                     //  Else:
    r+"";                //   Return the random integer [-128,127]
}                        // End of method `i(n)`
```